MIPS Infinite Loop using Keyboard and Display MMIO Simulator
Hi this is my first post here. I am making a maze game in mips that uses bitmap display and the Keyboard and Display MMIO Simulator for movement. I created my function that accepts the characters WASD and when I press any movement key the character moves infinitely in the direction I input. For example, pressing D once causes my character to keep moving right until my MARS crashes. I only want it to move once and then wait for a new input. Attached below is the code I am trying to debug. If possible I want to implement the jr $ra register into my code. Thanks
.eqv characterPos $t5

gameUpdateLoop:

        lw      $t3, 0xffff0004     # get input from user, then call appropriate movement function
    
        beq    $t3, 100, moveRight      # input d = move right
        beq    $t3, 97, moveLeft        # input a = move left
        beq    $t3, 119, moveUp         # input w = move up
        beq    $t3, 115, moveDown       # input s = move down
        beq    $t3, 120, exitGame       # input x = exit game
    
        jal gameUpdateLoop
    
moveRight:
        ### MOVE RIGHT ###
    
    addi characterPos, characterPos, 4
    sw  $t6, 0($t5)
    
    j gameUpdateLoop
moveLeft:
        ### MOVE LEFT ###

    addi characterPos, characterPos, -4
    sw  $t6, 0($t5)

    j gameUpdateLoop
moveUp:
        ### MOVE UP ###

    addi characterPos, characterPos, -256
    sw  $t6, 0($t5) 

    j gameUpdateLoop

moveDown:
        ### MOVE DOWN ###

    addi characterPos, characterPos, 256
    sw  $t6, 0($t5) 
    
    j gameUpdateLoop
    
exitGame:
    li $v0 10 
    syscall

I tried using jal instead of j to call back gameUpdateLoop. I am not sure what else can be the problem

You are not utilizing a complete MMIO pattern.  That pattern is,

wait for new character
input the character
handle it
repeat.

You're missing the first step.
The reason it doesn't do anything until you type a character is that it is (probably) inputting a 0 (nul character) when the program first starts, and, that causes looping without producing any visible actions.
But once you type a character, that is what is input, over and over and now the same infinite loop has a noticeable action on the program's environment.

The usual way to wait for new character is using polling in a busy-wait loop.
busywait:
    lw $t3, 0xffff0000
    andi $t3, $t3, 0x0001
    beq $t3, $zero, busywait

# now a new user-typed character is ready

    lw      $t3, 0xffff0004
    ...


Would something like that be enough to display?
busywait:
lw $t3, 0xffff0008
andi $t3, $t3, 0x0001
beq $t3, $zero, busywait
now a new user-typed character is ready
li $t0, 0x61
sw $t0, 0xffff000c

The ready bit is never set to 1
PS. It's connected to MARS. You code worked for keyboard, I'm trying to replicate.

@GeekSilva, yes, something like that should work.  You might try storing to the 0xc location once, initially, without polling for ready, in case it got stuck, which seems to happen occasionally when running/debugging the same program repeatedly without closing/reopening MARS.

Yeah, it worked! Thank you
